# CXX and C Compiler identification is unknown

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I've been really bugged out by this error. I'm trying to compile the OpenCV repository using CMake. I installed CMake using the Windows installer, the lastest one. However, I still can't properly build OpenCV properly. I'm new to using OpenCV and building using CMake. Here's the error log:

This is the command I used:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

This is what is displayed afterwards:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (project):
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:68 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Jessie James Suarez/Documents/GitHub/Vision/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Jessie James Suarez/Documents/GitHub/Vision/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Try specifying the generator (the [`-G` option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/ccmake.1.html)).

Comment: Which one should I set it to after?

Comment: The one for the compiler you're using to perform the build. Only you can answer that question.

Comment: Have you run the script that comes with visual studio which sets all the console environment variables?

Comment: I tried it but it still isn't working. I also used the CMake GUI but it gives the same error.

Comment: This means CMake did find a compiler but it wasn't able to compile a simple test program. Please take a look at `CMakeFiles\CMakeError.log` and add the error message there to your question. The last time I had this problem was when my Visual Studio 2012 Professional standard installation did not install any Windows SDK. E.g. do you have any `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v[some version]\bin\RC.Exe` file?